# Getting data from XML and parsing to Array

Tags: php, xml

currently I'm trying get all necessary data inside xml file and inserting to an array.

I cannot put the link of the XML file here, because contain private data from my company, but I'll simulate one. Check out below:

```
<main>

<item>
<title>
House 1
</title>
<text>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</text>
<link>
http://server25.dataxex.com/priv/auth/data/1/
</link>
</item>

<item>
<title>
House 2
</title>
<text>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</text>
<link>
http://server25.dataxex.com/priv/auth/data/2/
</link>
</item>

<item>
<title>
House 3
</title>
<text>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</text>
<link>
http://server25.dataxex.com/priv/auth/data/3/
</link>
</item>

...

</main>
```

I'm trying create a script that will read all  and get all ,  and , after that, insert to an array.

At this moment I just have this piece of code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$feed = "https://<private link>.com/data.xml";

$page = file_get_contents($feed);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page);

$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$text = $doc->getElementsByTagName('text');
$link = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');

foreach($arr as $doc) {
  $arr = array("title"=>$title,"text"=>$text,"link"=>$link);
}
var_dump($arr);
```

This code is not working. Can you help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through all of the item elements and get the content of the elements inside them.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$output = [];
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');

$fields = ['title','text','link'];
foreach($items as $currItemNode)
{
    $currOutput = [];

    foreach($fields as $currFieldName)
    {
        $currValue = $currItemNode->getElementsByTagName($currFieldName)[0]->nodeValue;
        $currOutput[$currFieldName] = trim($currValue);
    }

    $output[] = $currOutput;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Edit:

For older PHP versions (before 5.6.3), you have to treat the results of getElementsByTagName a bit differently, you have to do this:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$output = [];
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');

$fields = ['title','text','link'];

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
    $currOutput = [];

    foreach($fields as $currFieldName)
    {
        $currValue = $items->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($currFieldName)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $currOutput[$currFieldName] = trim($currValue);
    }

    $output[] = $currOutput;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Hey sir! I'm getting this error: **<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\result.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />**

Comment: Line 19 is the first line after foreach {

Comment: You must be using an old version of PHP. I'll update the answer to work with older versions.

Comment: It's working! But do you know how can I get the output in UTF-8?

Comment: Unless your input specifies a different encoding, UTF-8 is the default, so it should already be in UTF-8. If you are displaying on a web page, make sure your web server is sending the correct content type header (should be something like "text/html; charset=utf-8")

Comment: My website company is not showing in UTF-8, I'm getting words like: **pr&oacute;xima**, **At&eacute**, **&eacute**, etc. Do you know a way to solve it? *utf8_encode* is not working

Comment: That's not a UTF8 problem, it sounds like the text has been run through htmlentities() twice. The first run through would convert the accented characters into the HTML entities, which would display fine, the second run through changes the ampersands into &amp;

If you view source on the page, does it show something like "pr&amp;oacute;xima, At&amp;eacute;"? If so, trace through from the raw XML to where the content is placed in the HTML and see how it looks at each stage.

It may be encoded in the XML (common if CDATA sections are not used) and something is encoding it again at some point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181991/discussion-between-karlna-and-rob-ruchte).

Answer (score 0):

So you could check out [`xml_parse_into_struct`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)

```
$xmlparser = xml_parser_create();

xml_parse_into_struct($xmlparser,$page,$values);
xml_parser_free($xmlparser);

foreach($values as $value) {
  print_r($value);
}
```

This would put all your content from the XML file into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_variable)
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

// loop through the array

for($array as $arr){
    // Use var_dump($arr); to debug your array tree
}
```

[Simple xml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) as a reference